# What is purpose of res; in following struct?

Tags: c++, struct, declaration, definition, typespec

```
struct response {
    string resp[MAXSIZE];
    string type[MAXSIZE];
    int n;
}res;
```

Comment: That defines a struct `response` and then immediately creates an instance of that struct called `res`

Answer (score 2):

It is a declaration of an object with the name `res` of the type `struct response`.

A structure definition can be used as a type specifier similarly like

```
int res;
```

but instead of the type int you may place the structure definition

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    struct Hello
    {
        const char *hello;
        const char *world;
    } hello = { "Hello", "World!" };

    std::cout << hello.hello << ' ' << hello.world << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello World!
```

You could write the declaration of the object `hello` in one line like

```
struct Hello {  const char *hello; const char *world; } hello = { "Hello", "World!" };
```

But this is less readable.

In fact it is the same as if to write

```
    struct Hello
    {
        const char *hello;
        const char *world;
    }; 

    Hello hello = { "Hello", "World!" };
    // or 
    // struct Hello hello = { "Hello", "World!" };
```

Comment: Thank you . This makes more sense.